# Strange default Navbar alignment

Tags: html, css

I tried creating a navbar however for some reason, I have small gaps and when I try to use margins to close up the gaps the gap on the other side opens up. If I try to find a middle ground, I get 2 gaps on the left and right instead. Apparently it is impossible for me to fully up cover the whole upper area with my navbar.

Link to the example:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/Vk5Md/3/
```

And I had to modify my body with margins otherwise there will be a gap at the top too, is there another way to solve it?

```
body {
    background-image:url('../images/subtle_grunge.png');
    background-repeat:repeat;
    margin-left: 4px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Basically I would like to have my navbar look almost like the navbar on stackoverflow where there are no gaps between the address bar, the left side of the browser and the scroller on the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space that you see is for `body` and in some browser, for `html`. Just set the `margin` and `padding` to `0` for this two elements:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Demo of RAW implementation:

- [Here is FIDDLE Demo without removing the gap.](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/JNKQz/)
- [Here is FIDDLE Demo by removing the gap.](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/JNKQz/1/)

<kbd>**[Working FIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/Cb5eA/)**</kbd> for your demo.

Answer (score 0):

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

try this in the beginning of css file or code

Answer (score 0):

It's the default margin on the body element, which you can remove with

```
body {margin: 0;}
```

Consider adding a "CSS reset" to your file. E.g.

```
html, body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, a, blockquote, pre, code, hr, img, form, fieldset, legend, label, textarea, span, em, strong, sub, sup, cite, table, tbody, td, tfoot, th, thead, tr, tt, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
```

Avoid using this:

```
* {margin: 0; padding: 0}
```

as it has a negative impact on some elements (such as form elements).

Answer (score 0):

Use this..

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-image:url('../images/subtle_grunge.png');
background-repeat:repeat;
 margin:0;  
}
```

Updated Your Fiddle here:[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Vk5Md/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Is this something what you are trying to achieve? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vk5Md/8/) fully up cover the whole upper area with your navbar?
[image]

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <!-- Navbar==================================================- ->
<div id="nav">
     <ul> 
         <li><a href="#">Home</a></li> 
         <li><a href="#">Crawler</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Visual Analytics</a>
          </li> 
     </ul> 
</div>
</div> 
    </form>
</body>
```

```
body {
    background-image:url('../images/subtle_grunge.png');
    background-repeat:repeat;
}
#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
    height:100%;
    text-align: left;
}
#nav {
    list-style:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#b11d1d;
    text-align: center;
    opacity:0.5;
}
#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}
#nav li {
    display:inline;
}
#nav li a {
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color:#b11d1d;
    float:left;
}
#nav li a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #35af3b;
}
```

Note: If you want to increase the width of your nav, just add `padding-left:#px;` `padding-right:#px;` to `#nav li a`

Answer (score 0):

With `margin: 0;` in your body, you want to really define a CSS class for your navbar, something like this:

```
#navbar {
    top: 0;
    margin: 0;
    clear: both;
    background: #CCC url(img/clouds_header1.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

Then your HTML would look something like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="navbar">
        Put Nav Bar content here...
    </div>
</body>
```

[Live Example](http://phunkyplanet.com/test/navbar.html)